# difference between statuscode and getting status code through jqXHR in success/error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I came across jquery ajax status code online. But i am not sure what is the difference between this and getting status code through success and error. Any benefits of one over another?

```js
// With statusCode 
$.ajax({
  url: 'abc.com/123/456',
  type: 'get',
  data: {},
  statusCode: {
    200: function(response){
    },
    0: function(response){
    },
    404: function(response){
    }
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  
  },
  error:  function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     
  }
});

// withoutStatusCode
$.ajax({
  url: 'abc.com/123/456',
  type: 'get',
  data: {},
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  
  },
  error:  function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
       
     } else if (jqXHR.status === 404) {
       
     }
  }
});
```